# Add color to specific lines of a bash script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, colors

I'm trying to make a "Cryptocurrency news" script using curl and so far it works, but not completely the way I intended.

Here is the code for the main part of the script:

```
curl -s https://www.coindesk.com/ \
  | grep '<h3>\|datetime\|<p>' \
  | sed "s/<h3>//;" \
  | sed 's/timeauthor">//;' \
  | cut -d '>' -f2 | cut -d '<' -f1 \
  | head -46 \
  | tail -39 \
  | sed '3G;6G;9G;12G;15G;18G;21G;24G;27G;30G;33G;36G;39G'
```

I'm trying to add color to the lines containing the headline and the time, so it'll be easier to read. This has proven difficult.

First I created color variables, like this:

```
n=`echo -en "\e[0m"`
b=`echo -en "\e[1m"`
r=`echo -en "\e[31m"`
a=`echo -en "\e[36m"`
```

I've tried to add them to the script a couple of ways, but so far nothing has worked out.

Here is one example:

```
sed "s/<h3>/`echo "${r}${b}`/;" | sed 's/timeauthor">/`echo "${a}`/;'
```

I can't even get the color to show. Another problem is, even if I could, I'm not really sure how to add the ${n} variable to get the text back to normal again...

The entire "working" version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Color variables
 n=`echo -en "\e[0m"`
 b=`echo -en "\e[1m"`
 r=`echo -en "\e[31m"`
 a=`echo -en "\e[36m"`

# Prints news from coindesk.com
curl -s https://www.coindesk.com/ | grep '<h3>\|datetime\|<p>' | sed "s/<h3>//;" | sed 's/timeauthor">//;' | cut -d '>' -f2 | cut -d '<' -f1 | head -46 | tail -39 | sed '3G;6G;9G;12G;15G;18G;21G;24G;27G;30G;33G;36G;39G'
```

I'm fairly new to Linux and started bash scripting one week ago today, so this might not even be the best solution to accomplish what I'm looking to do.
Even the working parts seem "overly complicated" and a bit hacked together. Especially the head/tail parts, but that was the best I could come up with.

Comment: I would suggest using an rss feed for this instead if possible,

Answer (score 2):

### Short-and-simple answer

Use `tput setaf $COLOUR_CODE` to generate coloured output. Replace `$COLOUR_CODE` with an integer between `1` and `8`, pertaining to 8 basic colours (mapped to the sequences `\e[31m` to `\e[38m` respectively.

So in the case of your script:

```
# Color variables
n=`tput sgr0`
b=`tput bold`
r=`tput setaf 1`
a=`tput setaf 6`
```

### More detailed explanations

First of all, never use `echo` for outputting escape sequences like `"\e[31m"`. The command is a [portability train-wreck](http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html), and its `-n -e` switches aren't universally supported. Use `printf` instead:

```
printf '\e[31m'
```

This goes for other C-style escapes like `\n` and `\t` as well:

```
# Using Bash (Linux)
$ echo "foo\nbar"
foo\nbar

# Using Ksh (*BSD)
$ echo "foo\nbar"
foo
bar
```

Secondly, hard-coding ANSI escape codes isn't the best way to generate coloured output. The [`tput(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput) command exists for this purpose:

```
tput setaf 2  # Generates green text
tput bold     # Generate bold text
tput sgr0     # Reset those fancy effects

# To use them as variables:
bold=$(tput bold)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
reset=$(tput sgr0)
echo "${bold}HEADING${reset}"
```

Third, it's important to understand that coloured terminal output isn't universal between systems, terminal emulators, or hardware. `tput` mightn't even be available in some circumstances, and relying on highlighting to make TTY text readable is bad practice.

Comment: I don't believe this provides an answer to the question.  Please modify your answer to show OP how he can add colors to his output.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear enough.  In order to answer ops question you will need to actually complete his code in order to make it work.  As of now you are simply explaining how tput works.  Which, I agree tput is better suited for ops needs but that is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Jesse_b Ugh. I'm gonna leave this for somebody more familiar with conduct regulations and go back to lurking and voting on answers.

Comment: Here are some guidelines on answering questions if you are confused: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I'm still not sure how to integrate it in the code I have so far.

Comment: @discipulus I've updated the first half of my answer to show you which variables to update. I couldn't get your script to show any output when run locally.

Comment: That part I understand. What I can't seem to accomplish is to integrate it in the curl command part. Whatever I do, the colors isn't showing.

Comment: Alright, let's break it down. Your first challenge is extracting the relevant content areas from CoinDesk's homepage. **This alone is a headache.** Once you've got nearly-separated newsfeed articles sitting in different HTML files, then you can focus on applying colour.

Comment: @Alhadis:  His command works fine for me and presents the news articles in a very neat manner.

Comment: @Jesse_b Feel free to post the source code output in a gist somewhere

Comment: I wouldn't call it "source code output" but here: https://gist.github.com/jessebutryn/0a844b34c1ff24f69ccdd1068af05ef3

Comment: Right, that's really strange why I'm not seeing any output whatsoever. Probably something to do with BSD/Linux implementation differences or whatever.

Comment: @discipulus If your extracted output is arranged into three lines like that, then it's a simple loop to reapply highlighting:

    printf '%s%s%s' $red `head -1 $file` $reset